# How to implement a simple google web speech api with help of node,js

Tags: node.js, webspeech-api

I am looking for a step by step process. Or a good documentation that will help implement. So far I found this repo in github. But I could not understand how this can help https://www.npmjs.org/package/google-speech-api

Answer (score 1):

As the Google uses HTTP API you do not need to use any specific node module. That's why you could use simple HTTP request module to send/stream the file to google and get back the response. Here is small example how to do that https://gist.github.com/alotaiba/1730160.